# React other colors for different routes

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I have structure like this:

Component App:

```
<div className="App">
<Header></Header>
<Container></Container>
<Footer></Footer>
</div>
```

Component Container:

```
<Router>
<div className="container">
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Redirect to="/dash"/>)}/>
<Route path="/dash"
       render={(props) => ( <Dash data={this.state.data} 
                                  match={props.match}/> )}/>
<Route path="/prof" component={Prof}/>
<Route path="/rep" component={Rep}/>
</Switch>
</div>
</Router>
```

And my problem is that I want to have different colors of Header, Footer and some elements from components (Dash, Prof, Rep) according to current path. For example I want to have Header, Footer and bottom border 'red' when Dash is active or 'blue' when Rep is active. I already did it for bottom border, but I have problem how to pass this information (eg. css class name) for Footer and Header.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `react-router-redux`, you can get a current route in your store.
And in your Header Footer you can change a ClassName according to current route.